# std::priority_queue<struct with const member&> - 'operator =' function unavailable

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to add a struct with a const member& to a priority_queue.
Here's a minimal example of it:

```
#include <queue>

struct A
{
    A(const int& i)
        : m_i(i)
    {
    }
    bool operator<(const A& other) const
    {
        return m_i < other.m_i;
    }
    const int& m_i;
};

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<A> q;
    int i = 3;
    const int& f = i;
    q.emplace(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand the error for this

> Error  2   error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'A'    c:...\algorithm    2322

My A has no operator= overloaded, since it can't because of the const int& i.

I there a way to make this work?

The member needs to be a reference and only const functions can be called on this reference but I don't mind if the value in the struct is changed.

I tried using int& const m_i and implementing the operator= but then I can't initialize the emplace with a const int argument (and I probably don't understand enough what a & const is vs a const&).

Comment: Const references don't exist. You want a pointer-to-const here.

Comment: I started to figure as much, do you have any reference to the why?
Google just shows me pass by const ref links(instead of reference-to-const)

Comment: @turoni People use "const reference" when they mean "reference to const". There are no "const references" (in the literal meaning) because references aren't modifiable (can't be made to refer to another object), so the const qualifier would have no significance.

Comment: int a = 5, b = 6; 
int& c = a; 
c = b;
Am I not changing the reference in this case?

Comment: @turoni No. You're changing the referred object.

Comment: @turoni `std::cout << a << std::endl` will print `6` now. `c` is a reference to the object `a`. The statement `c=b` changes the referred object `a` but does not cause `c` to refer to another object

Comment: Thanks, that finally made me understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this using indirection. A (priority) queue requires the elements to be assignable. Pointers are assignable. So, instead of holding the non-assignable `A` objects, the queue could hold pointers to `A` objects. You may want the queue to own the elements, in which case you should use a smart pointer (at the cost of separate memory allocation for each element). Example:

```
std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<A>> q;
q.push(std::make_unique<A>(f));
```

---

On the other hand, you could easily make `A` assignable by using a pointer in place of the reference. I recommend that you ponder whether having a reference member really is a sensible requirement. For some reasons that force you to have a reference, a `std::reference_wrapper` (which is also assignable) might be sufficient.

Comment: Both easy and straightforward solutions thank you.
I will go with the pointer to A solution, I was just trying out something similar but needlessly more complex(custom wrapper types with pointers for A :p)